# В чем разница между алгоритмом А и А*?

Tags: алгоритм

В чем разница между А алгоритмом и А *?
И может ли быть А алгоритм с определенной оценочной функцией А * алгоритмом? (как это проверить?)

Comment: Впервые слышу про алгоритм А без звезды

Comment: Что такое "алгоритм А"  ?

Comment: @timob256, [A* search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)

Comment: @timob256 [ https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mccoy/courses/cisc4-681.12s/lec-materials/handouts/alg-a-search.pdf ]

Comment: @entithat  а  на русском есть информация по этому алгоритму ?? А то я не знаю английского

Comment: @timob256 [подойдет?](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_A*)

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов спасибо :3

Comment: вот тут прекрасная [реализация алгоритма на СИ++ и СИшарп](https://github.com/justinhj/astar-algorithm-cpp), [вот тут также есть](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0_A*) , [а тут прекрасный разбор, думаю лучшая ссылка :3](https://lsreg.ru/realizaciya-algoritma-poiska-a-na-c/)